# Apply git-diff patch with online tool

Tags: git, diff, patch, git-diff, git-apply

Is there a way to apply diff without Linux (have no permissions on work) or windows tools like WinMerge or (again have no permissions to install). The only way seems to be is to have an online tool :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, then you want to create a patch using git diff and apply it onto some file (given that git is at least installed on your system).

You can create a patch using `git diff`, then apply it simply using `git apply`. No online tool needed.

You can see detailed description in below links:
http://nithinbekal.com/posts/git-patch/

Detailed documentation for `git apply`.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply

Comment: Thanks. I kow how to apply patch if I have git installed. Problem was that I have no git on my work computer (and IT give no options to install it). That why i need exactly web version...